# Where (from Europe) to get a decent kit to start all-grain brewing?

Tags: all-grain, first-time-brewer, kits

I've been searching for a kit to start all-grain brewing, but seem to find nothing from Europe. My lack of knowledge might have something to do with this.

Comment: Are you in Europe, or trying to buy from Europe? If there is a homebrew shop near you, go there and ask them what you need. Hopefully they will be nice to you.

Comment: Where in Europe? I can give you a list of sites for the UK/Ireland but if you are on the mainland then I would probably recommend different suppliers.

Comment: Please add more details (which country in Europe)

Comment: I have known it to be cheaper to buy brew stuff from Ireland and have it shipped to southern Europe than to source it locally. So if price or perhaps choice is important then it is definitely worth considering cross border shopping.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite shop in the UK for all grain kits is [The Home Brew Shop](https://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/All-Grain-Brewing-Starter-Kits-1.html).

Otherwise as Barking.Pete says there is [BrewUK](http://www.brewuk.co.uk).

For brewing in France there is [Pico Mousse](http://www.picomousse.fr/picomousse/index.php?cPath=42).

[These guys ship across Europe from Belgium](https://homebrewshop.be/en/) site is available is French, English or Dutch.

If you are in Sweden then [Vinland](https://homebrewshop.be/en/) could help.

Also if in doubt a little bit of google, google translate and amazon and you should be able to get all the things you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are many all grain kits available to buy in Europe. The problem is not so much the ingredients as the equipment to handle all grain. That can range from a cool-box and a kettle, a simple Brew in a Bag system up to a BrewMeister automatic system.
Here are some links to a typical UK brew shop that sells a range of equipment and ingredients. BrewUK even does all grain starter courses so one can receive instruction before using any system.

[BrewUK intro to all grain brewing](https://www.brewuk.co.uk/blog/cat/Techniques/post/allgrain_fullmash/)

[All grain ingredient kits](https://www.brewuk.co.uk/beerkits/craftybrews/ag-starter-kits.html)

[All grain equipment starter sets](https://www.brewuk.co.uk/equipment/ag-equipment/all-grain-starter-sets.html)

This is just an example.There are many more. If one has never brewed before then an extract kits might be a good way to start. It gets the novice brewer used to handling the materials and the quantities involved and is somewhat simpler - but the beer is as good.